# how to get the userPrincipal saved in SecurityContext when websocket after connection

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-websocket

I now have a need to obtain the user information saved in SpringSecurity by the previous login request when the WebsocketSession connection of SpringBoot Websocket is established.
i have save the userPrincipal into the a session after login success.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticateToSession);
```

and then i will make a websocket request,but when i can get the Authentication when run the afterConnectionEstablished method.

```
@Component
public class ChatHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }
```

the result is null.

So i want to know how get the Authentication